# Mysql table name getting unwanted quotes resulting table does not exist error

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector

def add_features_to_db(stockname, timeframe, date, feature):
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='fx003')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    dbtable = stockname + timeframe
    mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO `%s` (date, trend) VALUES ( `%s`, `%s` )""" 

    record = (dbtable, date, feature) 
    cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query, record)
    conn.commit()
    
    print("Record inserted successfully")

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error))

finally:
    if conn.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")

add_features_to_db("aud-cad", "_30mins", "2021-09-24 21:00:00", "Short")
```

I have the code above and giving me the below error:

```
Failed to insert into MySQL table 1146 (42S02): Table 'fx003.'aud-cad_30mins'' doesn't exist
```

aud-cad_30mins table does exist and an insert query like below doing its job:

```
mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO aud-cad_30mins (date, trend) VALUES ( "2021-09-24 21:00:00","Short"  )"""
```

So when I try to use variables in the query, it gives the error. Why the table name getting unwanted quotes? Checked several tutorials but couldn't find a solution, any ideas?

Comment: `INSERT INTO ~%s~ ` --> `INSERT INTO %s ` - remove the quests

Comment: Failed to insert into MySQL table 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '~'aud-cad_30mins'~

Comment: no... remove the ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table name should be hardcoded in the query string instead of having it there as a placeholder `%s`, which is meant for the values to be inserted. So if you have the table name in the variable, you can replace it via `format()` before calling `cursor.execute()`

```
dbtable = stockname + timeframe
mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO {} (date, trend) VALUES ( %s, %s )""".format(dbtable)
```

see the examples [in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)

edit: as Bill mentioned in the comment, dont add the backticks around the `%s` placeholders.

Comment: Don't put back-ticks around the `%s` placeholders. The query-parameter handling in `cursor.execute()` will apply the right kind of quotes.

Comment: I just copy-pasted it from the question, but will edit that, thanks.

Comment: Do not forget to add % before the 2nd and 3rd % to have them stay in the query string after format.

Comment: @PtitXav I dont understand what you mean. `.format()` is not touching `%s` in any way.

Comment: Getting this, probably table name has dash in it. Any solutions for this or maybe I should remove the dashes from the table names... Failed to insert into MySQL table 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-cad_30mins (date, 
trend) VALUES ( '2021-09-24 21:00:00', 'Short' )' at line 1

Comment: when I removed the dashes from table names it worked...

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko : yep, you are write. It is python format..